# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, material-design

Hi I trying material design thing but I got the above error. Here is my log cat:

```
   Process: course.examples.healthcare_application, PID: 19653
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{course.examples.healthcare_application/course.examples.healthcare_application.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:904)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at course.examples.healthcare_application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/course.examples.healthcare_application-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:578)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:904)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at course.examples.healthcare_application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 24 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DDD">

</andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="course.examples.healthcare_application.MainActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package course.examples.healthcare_application;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Please help. I had looked at other posts but it doesn't solve my problem. And I am new to material design. Don't quite understand the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DDD">

</andorid.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Misspelled android

Answer (score 2):

**andorid**.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
to
**android**.support.v7.widget.Toolbar